# Mocking a file write process in googlemock

Tags: c++, file, mocking, googletest, googlemock

I am just starting with mocking using googlemock for a C++ project. In my case, my class to be tested observes a file that is written to, and whenever a minimal amount of new data has been written, it starts doing some work.

What I need is a mock class for the process writing to the file. As far as I understand things, I need to completely implement this "writing to file" functionality in form of (for googlemock) a virtual class from which a mock class is derived? The mock wrapper is finally used for testing and evaluation purposes, right?

Thanks for help!

Comment: How does the observation take place? Do you poll the file or is your class notified when data is written?

Comment: Hi. The observing class observes the filesize. The writer is the object in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that an object of your "observer" class is notified
that minimal amount of data has been written by an object of 
the "writter" class. In that case, you need to implement an abstract
class that represents an interface for your "writter" class, and have 
your real "writter" class inherit from it and override its virtual functions.
Also, have your mock "writter" class implementation inherit from this interface and
and create mock implementations using `MOCK_METHODn`.

Then, have your "observer" class receive notifications from "writter" object
using a pointer to the abstract class. This way, you can use dependency
injection to switch implementation during testing phase by creating a mock
"writter" object and passing its address to "observer" object (instead of an address to a real "writter"
object) and setup test cases using `EXPECT_CALL` on the mock object.

This is the best advice I can give since you did not provide us with a detailed description of your classes.

EDIT:

Concerning the implementation of your real "writter" class: You do not have to create it immediately, you can use the mock class for now to test the behavior of the "observer" class and leave the implementation for later. You will, of course, have to implement it eventually since it has to be used in production code.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply. The observing class, as you assumed, is notified. I want the mocker to simulate the file write process. What you described is basically what I understood I have to do -- the main focus was whether my derived writer class that implements the virtual class has to implement the writing to the file, whereas the mocking class is just for testing/evaluation purposes.

Comment: Sorry, it was not clear to me what the focus of the question was. Please check my updated answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for help! Things are clear now. However I proceed, I need to simulate the "minimal amount of change of filesize" in some way or another to get a realistic test.

Comment: Yes, and this simulation is best achieved using a mock because that insulates you from the environment (you are not actually writing to some file). Btw, you are welcome! Consider marking the answer as accepted if it was helpful.

Comment: But won't I have to change the observer in that case to not address a real file but "read the mocker"?

Comment: That is where dependency injection comes in. Observer hold a pointer to the interface, this means that it can receive an object of the real class or the mock class. This is usually done by adding a parameter (whose type is interface pointer) to constructor for observer class.That way, you can select which "writer" implementation to use when constructing observer object. In production code, you create a real writer and pass its address to observer constructor. In test code, you create a mock object and pass its address to the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Mocks, in google mock terms, are objects used to validate that your code under test performs certain operations on them.

What you describe is not a mock, but a utility class that triggers your code under test operations.

What does your class do when it detects that the file it observes is written to? If, for instance, it performs a call to another object, then you could use a mock object to check that it gets called with the right parameters, e.g. the new bulk of data written to the file.

Comment: My problem is exactly what you describe: Do I have to implement the functionality of what you call a util class and put the mocker on top of it?

Comment: @gilgamash both things are independent. You do have to implement the util class. Whether you need a mock or not depends on what you do when your class detects that new data has been written to the file.